# How to verify check box is selected in selenium WebDriver if its attribute "checked" is not present?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to verify check box is selected or not and in html code attribute checked is not present.
so I am unable to verify if any one can help me how to verify check box is selected in this condition.

Comment: Please share the relevant html code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method in the WebElement class

```
element.isSelected()
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below sample program which help you to get exactly you want :

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

     driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F%3Fpc%3Dtopnav-about-en");


     boolean enabled = driver.findElement(By.id("SkipCaptcha")).isEnabled();

    if(!enabled)

    {


        System.out.println("Already checked");



    }
    else

    {

        driver.findElement(By.id("SkipCaptcha")).click();



    }



     }
```

You will get more idea by running above program. Skipcaptcha is checkbox there.